# Should Page_Load method hit if using Update Panel in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, pageload

I am using Ajax control `Update panel`, i have tested that other controls are not refreshed but `Page_load` event is hit and all instance veriables are resetted, please tell me if this is supposed to behave this way, if yes please sugest how to avoide `Page_Load` method.

Comment: Yes, the full page's lifecycle is passed through in an asynchrounous postback via `UpdatePanel`s. Why do you want to avoid it? If you don't want it you could use webservices/webmethods instead.

Comment: Hello, sorry if I misunderstood, but I think you didn't get the idea in asp.net (I guess you're using webforms). Everytime a postback occurs all variables are initialized again, to keep the state of your variables you must store them in a Session or Cache. It doesn't matter if you're using UpdatePanels or not, this behaviour stays the same. Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid it try placing this in your `Page_Load`:

```
if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).IsInAsyncPostBack == false) {
}
```